# Combo Box Marked Dirty in Ext Grid Panel with no Changes

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a grid panel with a multi select combo box. If I just click into the combo box and click out, without making any changes, the combo box is marked as dirty. I want the combo box to not be marked dirty if no changes occur.

Here's a fiddle example of the issue:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13ov

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a listener to "validateedit" and return false if the before and after values are the same to prevent the red triangle appearing. The combobox itself is not in a dirty state, but the cell is unless you return false in the listener.

Eg.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit : 1,
    listeners: {
        validateedit: function(editor, context, eopts) {
            // return false here when you need to
            // new value: context.value
            // old value: context.record.data
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another thread about this bug in Ext The last post in this thread by sencha user martin.poitras contains a solution that would fix all multi select combo boxes.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257287